# MySQL syntax mistake

Tags: java, mysql

When I try to execute:

```
SELECT matricula  FROM lss_alumnos WHERE lss_alumnos.division = 'PREP';
```

I get this message:
`SQLException:` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'.division = 'PREP''` at line 1

And I am also using `MySQL` Workbench, and there I got the right result.

Comment: Do not include ";" for your String that stores the SQL query. It's a separator meant for the SQL development environment. The correct syntax should be just `String query = "SELECT matricula FROM lss_alumnos WHERE lss_alumnos.division = 'PREP'";`

Comment: can you post Full Java line?? First try remove that semicolon and if it does not work post full java line.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the qualified name `lss_alumnos` before the column name, also, remove the leading `;`.

```
SELECT `matricula` FROM `lss_alumnos` WHERE `division` = 'PREP'
```

(It's also a good practice to surround the names with the **`** symbol).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the comments are closer to the truth than the only other answer. To be sure, this query will work:

```
SELECT la.`matricula` FROM `lss_alumnos` la WHERE la.`division`='PREP'
```

Edit: I checked. None of these words are a MySQL reserved word http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html. It must be the semicolon